# Appending module sys.path.append

Tags: python, sys.path

I am running a python script on a local server (my OS is Ubuntu 20.04). The script is located here:

```
/var/www/html/myfoo.py
```

I need to use numpy module. The module is located here:

```
/home/namae/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

I am appending the module:

```
try:
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/home/namae/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
    import numpy
except Exception as e:    
    print(e)
```

I am getting an error: `No module named 'numpy'`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Update:

1. Unfortunately, I ran into difficulties at the stage of installing conda and following the suggested solution.
2. `sys.executable` is `/usr/bin/python3`
3. `ls -lsa $(which python)` gives me in the working dir:

```
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  123 Apr 26 00:53 myfoo.py
```

4. The following helped me:

```
sudo cp /home/namae/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy* /var/www/html/
```

Comment: this isn't how you should be doing things at all to begin with. fiddling with `sys.path` programmatically is **almost never the correct approach**

Comment: Now, I cannot reproduce this, if I use a numpy installation in some virtual environment that has `numpy` installed in site-packages, and then open an interpreter in another environment and do your `sys.path` fiddling,  I get a completely different error about importing C-extensions, which makes sense, because for complicated modules like numpy, you can't just naively add `site-packages` to the PATH and expect it all to work

Comment: So, what does `ls -lsa $(which python)` give you? Or perhaps show us `sys.executable`

Comment: Note, the location of the script is really not relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Create an `environment.yml`:

```
name: myfoo

channels:
- conda-forge

dependencies:
- numpy >= 1.23.5
```

Activate the environment. Observe that

```
$ python -c 'import numpy'
```

silently succeeds.

Comment: Unfortunately, I  ran into difficulties at the stage of installing conda and following the suggested solution. Once I solve the problem I work with your solution. It seems reliable